# Checking and closing HANDLE

Tags: c++, windows, handle

I am working with `HANDLES`, the first one, `nextColorFrameEvent` is an event handler and the second one is a stream handler. They are being initialized in the following piece of code:

```
nextColorFrameEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL );
hr = nui->NuiImageStreamOpen(
            NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR,
            NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,
            0,
            2,
            nextColorFrameEvent,
            &videoStreamHandle);
```

I want to properly deal with them on destruction, while not creating errors at the same time. Sometimes the initializer wont be called, so both HANDLEs are still NULL when the software comes to an end. Thats why I want to check first if the HANDLEs are properly initialized etc. and if they are, I want to close them. I got my hands on the following piece of code for this:

```
    if (nextColorFrameEvent && nextColorFrameEvent != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)CloseHandle(nextColorFrameEvent);
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    qDebug()<< error;
#endif
    if (videoStreamHandle && videoStreamHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)CloseHandle(videoStreamHandle);
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
    error = GetLastError();
    qDebug()<< error;
#endif
```

But this is apperently incorrect: if I do not run the initializer and then close the software this piece of code runs and gives me a 6:

```
Starting C:\...\Qt\build-simpleKinectController-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\simpleKinectController...
6 
6 
C:\...\Qt\build-simpleKinectController-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\simpleKinectController exited with code 0
```

which means:

> ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE 6 (0x6) The handle is invalid.
>   Which means that closeHandle ran anyway despite the tests. What tests should I do to prevent closing when the handle is not a valid HANDLE?

Bonus question: if I run the initializer this error will no longer appear when only closing colorFrameEvent, but will still appear when closing videoStreamHandle:

```
Starting C:\...\Qt\build-simpleKinectController-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\simpleKinectController...
0 
6 
C:\...\Qt\build-simpleKinectController-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\simpleKinectController exited with code 0
```

Do I need a diffent function to close a stream handler?

Comment: `GetLastError` is called everytime, isn't it?

Comment: I mean that `GetLastError` function is called in both cases: failure (when HANDLE is invalid) and success (when HANDLE is valid). That's a bit of strange.

Comment: Why? If the CloseHandle function went ok it returns a 0.

Comment: You haven't initialized `videoStreamHandle` before the `NuiImageStreamOpen` call. It's better to initialize it to an invalid value yourself rather than relying on the API call. The API documentation only guarantees that it will report error through it's return value, it says nothing about the out parameters.

Comment: You should only call GetLastError if CloseHandle returns 0.  Generally, when a Win32 API function succeeds, the result of GetLastError is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nui->NuiImageStreamOpen(...)` does not create a valid Windows handle for the stream but instead it creates an internal handle inside the driver side.
**So you can not use windows API to release/close stream handle !!!**

- To do that just call `nui->NuiShutdown()`. I have not yet used the callback event but I think its a valid windows handle and should be closed normally.
- if you need just to change settings you can always call `nui->NuiImageStreamOpen(...)` with new settings. No need to shutdown ...
- I would also welcome function `nui->NuiImageStreamClose(...);` because current state of **API** complicates things for long term running aps with changing sensor configurations.

Answer (score 2):

CreateEvent (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx) returns NULL if an event was not created.

You are checking against INVALID_HANDLE_VALID which is not NULL.

Comment: Thats what the first part is for: if (nextColorFrameEvent &&. If nextColorEvent was not properly initialized and thus is NULL, this will translate to 0 in the if statement, thus it will not run. Right?

Comment: If you check the return value from CreateEvent and its NULL, what is the LastError value?

Comment: Also, your code after the CloseHandles, doesn't show which one caused the error.  it could be either.

Comment: Updated the OP for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to double-close a handle. That is likely to generate `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE 6`. You can't detect this with your test, because the first `CloseHandle(nextColorFrameEvent);` did not change `nextColorFrameEvent`.

The solution is to use C++ techniques, in particular RAII. There are plenty of examples around how to use `shared_ptr` with `HANDLE`. `shared_ptr` is the standard solution to run cleanup code at most once, after everyone is done, and only if anybody actually allocated a resource.

Answer (score 0):

there is a good way of debugging that I'm particularly fond of, despite being all writen in macros, which are nasty, but in this case they work wonders.

[Zed's Awesome Debug Macros](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex20.html)

there are a couple of things I like to change though. They make extensive use of goto, which I tend to avoid, specially in c++ projects, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to declare variables mid-code. This is why I use exit(-1) instead, or, in some projects, I mod the code to try, throw, catch c++. Since you are working with Handles, a good thing would be setting a variable and telling the program to close itself.

here is what I mean. Take this piece of code from the macros (i assume you would read the exercise and familiarize with the macros):

```
#define check(A, M, ...) if(!(A)) { log_err(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); errno=0; goto error; }
```

i'd change

```
goto error;
```

to something like

```
error = true;
```

the syntax inside the program would be something like, and I took it from a multithread program I'm writing myself:

```
pRSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, MAX_TAM_ARQ, (LPCWSTR) "p_read_semaphore");
check(pRSemaphore, "Impossible to create semaphore: %d\n", GetLastError());
```

As you can see, GetLastError is only called when pRSemaphore is set to null. There are somewhat fancy mechanisms behind the macro (at least they are fancy for me), but they are hidden inside the "check" mask, so you needn't worry about them.

next step is to treat the error with something like:

```
inline void ExitWithError(bool &err) {
    //close all handles
    //tell other related process to do the same if necessary
    exit(-1);
}
```

or you could just call it inside the macro like

```
#define check(A, M, ...) if(!(A)) { log_err(M, ##__VA_ARGS__); errno=0; ExitWithError(); }
```

hope I could be of any help